# Jackson ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unrecognized field

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got this json file

```
[
   {
      "foo":{
         "comment":null,
         "media_title":"How I Met Your Mother",
         "user_username":"nani"
      }
   },
   {
      "foo":{
         "comment":null,
         "media_title":"Family Guy",
         "user_username":"nani"
      }
   }
]
```

So it's an array of Foo entities.

Then I've got my Foo object:

```
    import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonRootName;

    @JsonRootName("foo")
    public class Foo {

        @JsonProperty
        String comment;
        @JsonProperty("media_title")
        String mediaTitle;
        @JsonProperty("user_username")
        String userName;

/** setters and getters go here **/

    }
```

Then I've got my my FooTemplate as follows:

```
public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return java.util.Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(buildUri("/foos.json"),
            Foo[].class));
}
```

But when I run my simple test I get:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Unrecognized field "foo" (Class org.my.package.impl.Foo), not marked as ignorable at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@554d7745; line: 3, column: 14] (through reference chain: org.my.package.impl.Foo["foo"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Exception` suggests that it is trying to deserialize the `JSONObject`'s (the ones that are elements of the top level `JSONArray`) into `Foo` objects.  So you do not have an array of `Foo` entities, you have an array of objects that have a `Foo` member.

Here is what the `ObjectMapper` is trying to do:

```
[
   {            <---- It thinks this is a Foo.
      "foo":{   <---- It thinks this is a member of a Foo.
         "comment":null,
         "media_title":"How I Met Your Mother",
         "user_username":"nani"
      }
   },
   {            <---- It thinks this is a Foo.
      "foo":{   <---- It thinks this is a member of a Foo.
         "comment":null,
         "media_title":"Family Guy",
         "user_username":"nani"
      }
   }
]
```

It is because of this the the `Exception` complains about

> Unrecognized field "foo" (Class org.my.package.impl.Foo)

Perhaps you would like to take out the first `JSONObject`, and get rid of the `foo` identifier.

```
[
   {
      "comment":null,
      "media_title":"How I Met Your Mother",
      "user_username":"nani"
   },
   {
      "comment":null,
      "media_title":"Family Guy",
      "user_username":"nani"
   }
]
```

***EDIT***

You can alternatively create a new `Bar` object that will hold a single `Foo` instance, and attempt to unmarshall to an array of that.

```
class Bar {
    @JsonProperty
    private Foo foo;

    // setter/getter
}

public List<Bar> getBars() {
    return java.util.Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(buildUri("/foos.json"),
            Bar[].class));
}
```